# Exporting tags from Custom Vision

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the Azure Custom Vision service (customvision.ai) for data labelling. It works well for automatically labelling data.

I want to use this data for a custom neural network, so I want to download the tags. Is there a way to download the tags, either from the GUI or API?

The closest thing I have found is the GetTaggedImages API request (https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Training_3.2/operations/5dddfe4dc8d30b100855c60c).

Thanks!

Comment: You mean just the list of existing tags? Or images with their tags?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all tags for a given project and iteration., I would recommend you use API directly. There is a GetTags API can help with this, pleae check the following API reference:

https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Training_3.2/operations/5dddfe4ec8d30b100855c626